# Javascript ajax (get)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to do a simple table and the data is populated by php/mysql on wordpress.

My objective is: when the user click on a `<th>`, the ajax will reload the table with a `get` parameter, so the table will be ordered by the specific column.

If I access my URL like this: `localhost/table?data=desc or localhost/table?data=asc` it works, but I want to do that with ajax. Here's part of my code:

JS:

```
    $(document).on('click','#order_data',function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/table?data=desc',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#main_container").load(location.href + " #table_demos");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```html
<div id="main_container">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="table_demos">
 <thead>
  <th id="order_data">Data
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data'] == 'asc') {
   echo '<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
  } else if(isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data'] == 'desc') {
   echo '<i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
  }
  ?>
  </th>
  <th>Versus</th>
  <th>Mapa</th>
  <th>Placar</th>
  <th>Baixar</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<?php
 $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","321","local_test");

 if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Falha na conexão MySQL.";
   } else {
  $data = '';
  if(isset($_GET['data'])) {
   if($_GET['data'] == 'asc') {
    $data = 'order by data asc';
   } else if($_GET['data'] == 'desc') {
    $data = 'order by data desc';
   } 
  }
  $query = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM demo_cadastro {$data}");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . transformar_data($row['data']) . '</td>';
   echo '<td><a href="' . $row['link_adversario'] . '" target="_blank">' . $row['nome_adversario'] . '</a></td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['mapa'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $row['pontos_marcados'] . 'x' . $row['pontos_sofridos'] . '</td>';
   if($row['link_demo'] == '#') {
    echo '<td><a href="' . $row['link_demo'] . '" class="demo-indisponivel-swal"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>';
   } else {
    echo '<td><a href="' . $row['link_demo'] . '"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>';
  }

  mysqli_free_result($query);
 }

 mysqli_close($conexao);
  
 function transformar_data($data) {
  $data_explode = explode('-', $data);
  return $data_explode[2] . '/' . $data_explode[1] . '/' . $data_explode[0];
 }
?>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I think i'm messing up just the ajax call...

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$(document).on('click','#order_data',function() {
    $("#main_container").load('/table?data=desc');
});
```

(You are sort of mixing ajax call and the load-functionality. I believe the latter will work for you.)

Comment: Works fine now, thanks! But it was loading the whole html on the div, so i added the table id.

    $("#main_container").load('/table?data=desc #table_demos');